# Is there any bootstrap class for expanding row height depending on the content of one of the columns?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap styles in my razor page. I have a row with 3 columns and the second column is a label which is overlapping the 3rd column when there are too many characters. How can it change the height of the row so the label will not overlap the 3rd column? Is there any built in bootstrap class for this? Thank you!

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
        <select class="form-control" @bind="@SelectedAction">
            <option class="dropdown-item-text" value="1" selected>Action1</option>
            <option class="dropdown-item-text" value="2">Action2</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-8">
        <label class="control-label">@FreeFormText</label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" @onclick="@Send">
            Send
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a style flex-wrap in bootstrap. So I can just apply that to div element.

```
<div class="col-8 flex-wrap">
    @FreeFormText
</div>
```